# Expo-2d-context can only draw text to one GLView. Any other GLView shows block letters

Tags: javascript, android, ios, react-native, expo

I have a component where I need multiple GLViews using expo-2d-context to manipulate them like an HTML canvas. Everything works fine except for drawing text. Calling `await ctx.initializeText()` only seems to work correctly on the first GLView.

The example below results in this:
[image: Example]

Here's a reproducible example (**NOTE**: this cannot run in an expo snack because of the asynchronous calls to onContextCreate. However, I've set up a snack [here](https://snack.expo.io/@thejlyons/great-carrot) that you could download and run).

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import { GLView } from 'expo';
import Constants from 'expo-constants';
import Expo2DContext from 'expo-2d-context';

export default class App extends React.Component {
  _onGLContextCreate = async (gl, text, color) => {
    var ctx = new Expo2DContext(gl);
    await ctx.initializeText();

    ctx.fillStyle = color;
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, ctx.width, ctx.height);

    ctx.fillStyle = "white";
    ctx.font = "italic 72pt sans-serif";
    ctx.fillText("Hey Galaxy", 10, 100);

    ctx.flush();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <GLView
          style={{ flex: 1, height: 200, width: '100%' }}
          onContextCreate={(gl) => { this._onGLContextCreate(gl, "View 1", "#333399") }}
        />

        <GLView
          style={{ flex: 1, height: 200, width: '100%' }}
          onContextCreate={(gl) => { this._onGLContextCreate(gl, "View 2", "#993333") }}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    paddingTop: Constants.statusBarHeight,
    backgroundColor: '#333333',
    padding: 8,
  }
});
```